# Inequalities for Motzkin polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Let us denote by $M_{n}(t)$ the $n$-th Motzkin polynomial. It is defined by $M_1(t) = M_2(t) = 1$ and
$$ M_{n}(t) = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor } \frac{1}{n-1-i} \binom{n-1-i}{i} \binom{n-1}{i+1} t^i$$
for $n\geq 2$ (see for instance sequence A055151 in the OEIS). I have a conjecture that would simplify a very intricate proof in a paper I am working on.

> For every $1\leq k \leq n-1$ the following inequality is true coefficient-wisely
> $$M_{k}(t) M_{n-k}(t) \leq M_{n-1}(t)$$

For instance, for $n = 11$ and $k = 3$, we have
$$35t^4 + 105t^3 + 91t^2 + 22t + 1 \leq 126t^4 + 420t^3 + 252t^2 + 36t + 1.$$

For $n=13$ and $k=5$, we have
$$70t^5 + 350t^4 + 497t^3 + 198t^2 + 27t + 1 \leq 462t^5 + 2310t^4 + 2310t^3 + 660t^2 + 55t + 1$$

I tried to prove this with two different approaches:

1. Writing down the explicit convolution and trying to compare coefficient by coefficient using Vandermonde-like identities.
2. Using the interpretation of the coefficients of $M_n(t)$, using the enumeration of certain lattice paths (see for instance Chapter 4 of the book "Eulerian numbers" by Petersen).

In both cases the details become very intricate and I get stuck. It seems to me that this inequality should be true for a good reason, but I am not being able to actually prove it. Any help or reference would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It may be useful if you include the combinatorial description of the coefficients as numbers of lattice paths to the post

Comment: I am utterly confused about your indexation: first, the formulae for the coefficients make no sense for $n=1,2$ and second,  the polynomial you write for $n=11$ is counting Motzkin paths with $i$ up steps from $(0,0)$ to $(9,0)$, not from $(0,0)$ to $(11,0)$. Is that how you really wanted it?

Comment: @fedja About $n=1, 2$, I forgot to explicitly say that the polynomials are defined then as $M_{1}(t)=M_{2}(t) = 1$. Yes, I know the indexing is strange, but I really want to consider things as they are stated. I put an extra example to avoid any possible confusions.

Comment: So your $n$-th polynomial counts Motzkin paths to $(n-2,0)$, right? Sorry for asking again but I'd better make sure I have everything right in my head before turning the brains on :-)

Comment: @fedja If I am not confusing things (this is tricky because of the different indexing in different sources), it should be
$[t^i] M_n(t) = \# \{\text{Dyck paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n-1,0)$ with $i$ up steps}\}$. This at least makes sense with Figure 3 here https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v22i2p8/pdf and the fact that $M_5(t) = 2t^2+6t+1$.

Comment: Erm. With that $M_5$, how did you get $36t$ for $n=11$ and $55t$ for $n=13$ then? Those are, clearly ${n-2\choose 2}$, aren't they?

Comment: For $n=11$ the right-hand-side of the inequality is $M_{10}(t)$, and the linear term is $\frac{1}{8}\binom{8}{1}\binom{9}{2}= \binom{9}{2}=36$. I think that it might be less awkward to state the inequality in the following equivalent way. Proving $M_k(t) M_{n-k+1}(t) \leq M_n(t)$, and ask $1\leq k\leq n$.

Comment: Ah, OK. My bad. So Motzkin paths to $(n-1,0)$ then. Makes sense now :-)

Comment: However now the question becomes why that is not a trivial consequence of the fact that the concatenation of Motzkin paths of lengths $k-1$ and $n-k-1$ is a Motzkin path of length $(n-1)-1$. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @fedja Because the LHS may count the same Motzkin path twice, while the RHS, don't.

Comment: @LeechLattice How? The full path of length $n-2$ determines both its beginning of length $k-1$ and its end of length $n-k-1$ uniquely, doesn't it? You would be perfectly right if there were a summation over $k$ on the left, but the $k$ is fixed, or I misunderstand something?

Comment: I think that fedja is right and the solution to the inequality is a direct consequence of the interpretation I stated above. Probably I got messed up with the indexing at some point. Thank you.